# How to get userId on client without storing the jwt on client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, userid

Im using jwt in my react native/node app. I do not store it on the client and dont want/need to. In one case I need to know the userId on client but only have the token (that i use to create jwt). I need it because I need to establish a connection only with specific users so I need to get the userId.

How can I do that without storing the jwt on client? Or do I just use the token on client, send that, and in my backend I verify the token to get the actual userId and then compare?

**client:**

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'example.com'
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
```

**backend**

```
app.use(router.get('/stream', requireAuth));
```

in requireAuth create the jwt

```
 jwt.verify(token, ...
```

and attach it to req.user.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to save the JWT on the client side? The point of the token is that it's signed by the server and can't be tampered with, so it should be safe to transmit it back and forth to establish a "session" and verify identity

Comment: I was just thinking since I dont ever need the jwt on the client except for one use case I didnt want to store because of that

Answer (score 1):

The best way to transfer a token from the BE to FE will be using HTTP-only cookies, with this you will not be able to read the token in FE using JS but it will automatically send with every request and you will be able to read it in the BE and get the userId and do relevant things with it.

[Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)